# How to call async function in futter FutureBuilder widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: dbHelper.abonnements(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data==null){
            return StartUpScreen();
          }else{
            final meterId = snapshot.data![0].meterId;
            final clientId = snapshot.data![0].clientId;
            final abonnement = snapshot.data![0];

            final compteur = await MeterAPIManager.getMeter(meterId);
            final user = await ClientAPIManager.getUser(clientId);

            return HomeScreen(abonnement: abonnement,compteur: compteur,user: user);
          }
        }
    );
```

Retriving varables **compteur** and **user** gives me errors. I cannot add async to my builder.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: How about waiting for multiple `Future`s using [`future.wait`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

Comment: If that were possible, what should be rendered while you're awaiting a `Future` in the builder? And why would we have `FutureBuilder` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of async and await within a function to perform asynchronous operations before returning the widget tree. However, you need to ensure that the function containing the asynchronous operations returns a widget.

```
  return FutureBuilder(
  future: dbHelper.abonnements(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // or any loading indicator
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    } else if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
      return StartUpScreen();
    } else {
      return _buildHomeScreen(context, snapshot.data!);
    }
  },
);

Widget _buildHomeScreen(BuildContext context, List<Abonnement> abonnements) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: _fetchData(abonnements[0].meterId, abonnements[0].clientId),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); // or any loading indicator
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        Abonnement abonnement = abonnements[0];
        Meter compteur = snapshot.data![0]; // Assuming _fetchData returns a List
        User user = snapshot.data![1]; // Assuming _fetchData returns a List

        return HomeScreen(abonnement: abonnement, compteur: compteur, user: user);
      }
    },
  );
}

Future<List<dynamic>> _fetchData(String meterId, String clientId) async {
  Meter compteur = await MeterAPIManager.getMeter(meterId);
  User user = await ClientAPIManager.getUser(clientId);
  return [compteur, user];
}
```

Comment: `future: _fetchData(meterId, clientId),` DO NOT build the future in the future: parameter of the FutureBuilder!

Answer (score 0):

you could do all work in function:

```
   Future<Abonement?> getAbonement()
        final abonnements = await dbHelper.abonnements();
        final abonnement = abonnements[0];
        if (abonnement == null) return null;
        
        final meterId = abonnement.meterId;
        final clientId = abonnement.clientId;
        
        final compteur = await MeterAPIManager.getMeter(meterId);
        final user = await ClientAPIManager.getUser(clientId);
        return compteur== null || user == null? null : Abonement(compteur, user);
      }
```

where:

```
class Abonement {
  const Abonement(this.compteur, this.user);

  final Compteur compteur;
  final User user;
}
```

and then in the state of stateful widget:

```
late Future<Abonement?> abonement;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    abonement = getAbonement();
  }

    return FutureBuilder(
            future: abonement,
            builder: (context,snapshot){ ...
```

p.s. thans to [@RandalSchwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz?tab=profile)

Comment: Don't build the future in the future: parameter of the FutureBuilder.  I have a video about this: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg